# Why the sentence 'The garden looks a mess.' is the only possible way to phrase it in terms of the use of tenses?

Tags: grammaticality

According to Michael Swan in his Practical English Usage (Fully Revised 2005) 'To talk about a temporary appearance, we can use simple or progressive forms; there is not much difference in meaning. You look/are looking very unhappy. What's the matter?'

Is the mentioned above situation applicable to the sentence about the garden? I am pretty sure the use of Present Simple Tense is the only possible way to say it. Why? Why not?

Comment: The key is "temporary" appearance: using the progressive makes it a bit clearer that you regard the mess as temporary, something that can be fixed.

Comment: so, IS it possible to use the present progressive tense in terms of the garden? @StoneyB

Comment: Yup. "The garden's looking rather a mess. Do you suppose you could tidy it up before Aunt Agatha comes?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While *is looking a mess* is not completely unheard of ([34 hits](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22is+looking+a+mess%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl) on Google Books) , *looks a mess* is far more common [8,960 hits](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22looks+a+mess%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl).

This might be because *[to look](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/look)* meaning

> Have the appearance or give the impression of being

might be considered to be a **[stative verb](http://www.perfect-english-grammar.com/stative-verbs.html)** i.e. non-continuous verb. These are the verbs that refer to states (experiences or conditions) and they are not generally used in progressive (continuous) forms.

I'd say that, according to evidence of usage, generally doesn't mean always. Even ODO gives an example of *to look* (in the meaning discussed) in a progressive tense:

> Recently he has been looking rather grim

Comment: Do you happen to know whether the usage of the Present Simple Tense in the sentence about the garden is dependent on the fact that it is an inanimate object while 'He has been looking rather grim' is used in reference a person?

Comment: @Yukatan In those 34 hits on Google Books some include inanimate objects (or the tense was used in reference to them) - some are: "this place is looking a mess", "his room is looking a mess", "her hair is looking a mess", "all is looking a mess" (I interpret this one as inanimate as well) etc. It seems that rules are generally dictated by usage. But the difference in usage in present simple and present progressive is vast in this case - so I would use it only if I have a strong reason to emphasize that the mess is strictly temporal (the last suggestion is just an opinion)

Comment: @Yukatan I made a grammar mistake, sorry: I would use it only if I **had** a strong reason to emphasize that the mess is strictly temporal... I really shouldn't type without any caffeine in the system; I tend to type rubbish then :-(

Comment: I omitted 'to' after the word 'refernce' in my first comment to your answer,  I hope nobody has died because of it:) @Lucky

Comment: @Yukatan I'm still alive :-). In fact I haven't even noticed... When I read other people's posts a look for meaning, when I read my own I look for mistakes ;-)

Comment: same here:) @Lucky